# Find the name of the current config file

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

Is there a way to find the name (and path) of the current application's config file from inside a class library?

E.g. in a web app this would be `web.config`, in a windows app or service this would be `myapp.exe.config`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

If that doesn't work, add references to System.Web and System.Configuration, then try this:

```
if(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath  == null) 
    return ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;
else
    return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Web.config");
```

Comment: Thanks. After a first test, the first approach seems to work for windows services and web apps.

Comment: I never accept answers immediately (but I will do), e.g. to be able to verify the solution and to give others a chance to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Configuration.FilePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.filepath.aspx):

> Gets the physical path to the configuration file represented by this Configuration  object.

Comment: Yeah, but then you need to have a "Configuration" element first... there's unfortunately no "Configuration.CurrentElement" or anything like that...

Comment: How would I get to an instance of Configuration?